# Arguments in favor of Eternal Return?

Tags: nietzsche

Are there any current modern mathematical or scientific arguments in favor of eternal return?
I have read several against it here on this site.

One which I could think of is that the Universe might not be entirely governed by mathematical rules.
There could be a different kind of logic at the base of it all, making time circular.
Causality might not be an entirely correct assumption.

But these are too presumptive and bold.
Does QM suggest finite number of states for matter under causal laws? And if so, does it follow that these finite states can only have a finite configuration under infinite space and time?

Comment: There are some similarly minded speculations in [modern cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Modern_cosmology) involving the multiverse and statistical arguments.

Comment: @Conifold, that links suggests alternate assumptions, than what Nietzsche made. I am also looking at something which does not involve a multiverse. Could you please point out what alternate assumptions those are? I do not find the wikipedia article on this exhaustive or clear enough, which is why I asked it here. It would also be great to know exactly why QM, or the uncertainty principle requires finite states for matter, if so.

Comment: Nietzsche's argument was based on classical statistical mechanics (or rather layman's simplification of it), the closest precise result is Poincaré recurrence theorem. Those are of course obsolete today, the "alternative assumptions" are those of modern physics, or rather interpretations of it. QM leads to finitely many states because of minimal size, finite volume can only be filled with finitely many parts no less than it. [Vilenkin has a version](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0102010) which does not involve multiverse but is similar.

Comment: @Conifold Doesn't a finite overall number of quantum number only ensures finitely many configurations if kinetic energy is also discrete? (Which would defy relativity).  Two frequencies in a continuous distribution can be forever out of synchronization, in the same way that a circle rolling around a square still never returns to its initial state.  So you need something in addition to ordinary QM to get to your result, no?

Comment: Kinetic energy of what? If energy is quantized and the range is finite there are finitely many states. Whether there is or is not continuous spectrum depends on the system, not on QM. Anyway, this is a subject for Physics SE.